# Using an existing function, how to define a new function with different default optional arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Given a function fxn1()

```py
def fxn1(a,b=1):
    return a*b
```

I would like to do something like:

```py
fxn2=fxn1(.,b=2)
```

In words, I would like to make a new function fxn2() which is identical to fxn1() but with different default values of optional arguments. I have not been able to find an answer/direction on web.

Comment: You may want to read about [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: It's called early binding. Use partial from functools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial` ([official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial)):

```
from functools import partial

def fxn1(a,b=1):
    return a*b

fxn2 = partial(fxn1, b=2)

print(fxn2(4))
```

Prints:

```
8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use partial function:

```
from functools import partial
fxn2 = partial(fxn1, b=2)

fxn2(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fxn1(a,b=1):
    return a*b

def fxn2(a,b=2):
    return fxn1(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be

```
def fxn2(a, b=2):
    return fxn1(a, b)
```

Comment: It should be `return fxn1(a, b)`

Comment: You are of course right, thanks for catching it :-)

Comment: Actually, the easiest way will be [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: Partial is arguably more *elegant*. I figured that for a beginner, the other option would be easier.